# How can I SUM a COUNT(*) subquery to find two string values per ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, sum

I'm trying to build a SQL Server query to spit out numbers. Specifically, I need to know how many people like both Pizza and Soda but displayed by only showing the proper count for relationship.

I have 2 tables that look like this:

`People`:

```
1 Andy        Relative
2 Jim         Friend
3 Anderson    Friend
4 Pamela      Relative
```

`Likes`:

```
1  Pizza
1  Soda
2  Pizza
3  Soda
4  Pizza
4  Soda
```

My desired output would be the following. A list of how many relatives and how many friends like Pizza and Soda:

```
Relative 2
Friend   0
```

This is pretty much where I'm at but this is wholly incorrect:

```
SELECT 
   relation,
   (select count(*) from likes lik where id = lik.id and pizzavalue = 'Pizza') 
   + 
   (select count(*) from likes lik where id = lik.id and pizzavalue = 'Soda') 
FROM 
   dbo.People
INNER JOIN 
   Likes lik on ps.id = lik.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select relation, count(*) 
from People p
join likes l1 on l1.id = p.id and pizzavalue = 'Pizza'
join likes l2 on l2.id = p.id and pizzavalue = 'Soda'
group by relation
```

This will get first join the person table to the likes table and leave us with every person that likes both soda and pizza.  The group by will return a single count per relation.

Comment: Looks perfect, thanks! Got me over a hurdle. I was way over-thinking this.